# Pseudocode Not Understand Line

Tags: python, pseudocode

Im just confused on Line 11 how to code it into python:

[image]

The Line is( FOR N <-- 1 TO Factor

Comment: `for n in range(1, Factor)`

Comment: This should be `for n in range(1, Factor + 1)`, as the upper bound of the range is not included.

Comment: You missed two early parts of the tutorial: [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and [The `range()` Function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function).

Comment: Please show what you already did, so we can see what you did first, and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `while loop`:

```py
n = 1
while n <= (Factor+1):
    # block of code
    n = n + 1
```

or as @Thierry Lathuille said, with `for-loop`:

```py
for n in range(1, Factor + 1):
    # block of code
```

Comment: If the number of loops is known a `for` loop is the better option since there's no need to do the handling of the counter yourself.

Comment: I did not write with `for-loop` because someone else, said it in the comments.